# how to know is this new or update data when using same form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to use one form both for adding and editing data. So I have two constructors like this

```
public AddEditForm(IBookRepository repository)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.repository = repository;            
}
public AddEditForm(IBookRepository repository, Book book)
            : this(repository)
{
    Book data = repository.GetDetails(book.Id);
    if (data != null)
    {
        PopulateFormFields(data);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could'nt find requested book!");
    }
}
```

My question is, when user hits ok button how would I know is this new record or update action?

Should I use private `Book _Book` property which will be populated when using second constructor and on btn ok action I need to check is that book exist inside database (is this unnecessary db round trip) or I should follow some better pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are passing in an existing `Book` so it would make sense for this to be the indicator you are *updating* a book. For readability, you could wrap it up in a nice property e.g.

```
public bool IsNew { get { return _book == null; } }
```

Or to avoid keeping a reference to the existing book you could make it a writeable property which get's set on the constructor i.e.

```
public AddEditForm(IBookRepository repository)
{
    IsNew = true;
    ...
}

public bool IsNew { get; private set; }
```

We don't need to set it to `false` in the overloaded constructor because `bool` [defaults to false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/83fhsxwc.aspx) in C#.